# Header Location not working after 3 times

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

I'm using the function `header("Location: example.php")` on a page that runs a MySQL query that creates a photogallery and then redirects to the page of the photogallery just created itself. 
The problem is that, after having created 3 or 4 photogalleries this error shows up:

> "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ..."

I know that before `header()` shouldn't be any output, but my question is: why it does work for a few times and then it fails?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['crea'])){

    $nome_lista = $_POST['nome_lista'];
    $slug_lista = str_replace(' ','_',$nome_lista);

    $luogo_lista = $_POST['luogo_lista'];

    $inserisci = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `prova`(`id_lista`, `nome_lista`,`slug_lista`, `id_utente`, `luogo_lista`,`copertina`) VALUES (NULL,'$nome_lista','$slug_lista','$user_id','$luogo_lista','copertina.jpg')");

    $user_id = $_SESSION['id_utente'];

    $id_lista = mysql_query("
    SELECT id_lista 
    FROM prova 
    WHERE id_utente ='$user_id'
    ORDER BY id_lista DESC");

    $ultima_lista = mysql_result($id_lista,0); 

    if($inserisci){
        $percorso_album = "./img_globali/".$user_id.$username;
        mkdir($percorso_album."/".$slug_lista, 0775);
    }else{
        echo 'Non ho inserito la cartella del nuovo album '.mysql_error();
    } 
    header("location: album.php?id=".$ultima_lista);
    exit;
}
?>
```

The query is executed, even though the page doesn't redirect

Comment: I guess sometimes it goes to `echo 'Non ho inserito la cartella del nuovo album '.mysql_error();`

Comment: Third-Fourth time, your `INSERT` query is failing, add debug statements to know what is happening ? NOTE: redirection may fail due to such debug statements. First, debug and then proceed with redirection stuff...

Comment: @Makesh The query is executed, even though the page doesn't redirect

Answer (score 2):

The headers must be sent before any content, remove any echo commands and it will work. Also, ensure there is no white space or HTML before this section of PHP code.

You can also turn on output buffering using `ob_start();` at the very top of your PHP code, and then the headers will be sent before any echo'd variables.

Comment: the use of `ob_start();` just hide the actual problem.

Comment: Not really, there really is no harm in just turning it on in almost all cases and could give you a small performance increase under some configurations.

Comment: I think there is no problem using ob_start, its mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974691/php-page-redirect-problem-cannot-modify-header-information) also

Answer (score 1):

In your condition the output is sent in `else` block only. So you will not get that error when `$inserisci` is `true`.

```
if ($inserisci){
    // No output here, so error will happen when in this block
    $percorso_album = "./img_globali/".$user_id.$username;
    mkdir($percorso_album."/".$slug_lista, 0775);       
 }else{
     // You have output here, hence "header already sent" error
     echo 'Non ho inserito la cartella del nuovo album '.mysql_error();

 } 
 header("location: album.php?id=".$ultima_lista);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location:album.php?id=$ultima_lista");
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a specificly similar issue today of header(Location...) not working after 3 times.

I realized that my issue was that i was inside an iframe, so the redirect kept me inside the iframe and adding a new stack...

After redirecting twice i had an iframe inside an iframe inside a iframe... I guess that's why the redirect was not working the 3rd time.

Instead you should redirect to top location :

```
echo("<script> window.top.location.href = 'myPage.php'</script>");
```

(I echoed the JS because my controller was not displaying anything in a view)

Hope it helps someone